# Non-existent slope (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I encountered this question, which I am having trouble understanding.

-> Find the slope of $f(t) = \sqrt{1 − \sin (2t)}$
(a) At the point (0,1).
(b) At the origin.
This seems to be a trick question. I found the derivative to be $$\frac{-\cos(2t)}{\sqrt{1-\sin(2t)}}$$ and although it does have a tangent at $x=0$, it's not equal to $1$ nor $0$. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. If $f(t)$ is a function of one variable, what is the meaning of it's slope at $(0,1)$?

Comment: Uniquesolution is correct. Is there any other context for the problem you are not providing?

Comment: @uniquesolution I am assuming it means that I should find the slope at that point (adding the y value doesn't make cause any problems). but because the y value is -1 instead of one, i think it might be a trick.